# Perl - Hashes Error - Undefined value as a symbol error

Tags: perl, parsing, hash

I am parsing a huge text XML file with XML::TWIG. I have to convert the data into standard CSV so that it can later be fed into the SQL database. The XML input file contains data of several customers. Some customers will have more data than others (more tags). So I have been putting all the data into hashes, so that I can differentiate the tag in hashes.

I reset the hash for every customer. Now as any customer can have additional tags, when I try to print out the hash for a key which was not defined, it will give the error:

```
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at xml.pl at line 129
```

The sample code is

```
print $hash(aKeyWhichWasNotDefined);
```

Is there anyway to print out an empty string if the hash key doesn't exist in hash?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you've written?  `$hash{aKeyWhichWasNotDefined}` would be a hash reference...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the correct syntax is:

```
$hash{aKeyWhichWasNotDefined};
```

You can use the defined-or operator as a quick solution:

```
print $hash{aKeyWhichWasNotDefined} // '';
```

`exists` and `defined` also let you check for a hash key.

```
if (exists $hash{key}) { print "key exists but the value could be undefined" }
if (defined $hash{key}) { print "key exists and has a defined value" }
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to get a hash value is

```
print $hash{aKeyWhichWasNotDefined};
```

That is, using `{` (curly braces) not `(` (parentheses).

You'll still get a warning if you print an uninitialised value. On Perl 5.10+ you can use the defined-or operator:

```
print $hash{'non-existent-key'} // '';
```

On earlier Perls, do it the hard way:

```
print defined $hash{'non-existent-key'} ? $hash{'non-existent-key'} : '';
```